# Codeigniter: User data not showing up on profile

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm still new to CI, so bear with me. But I'm having some trouble getting the data to show on user profiles.

Model:

```
public function user_data()
{
    $age = $this->session->userdata('age');
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('age', $age);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function user()
{   
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $data['row'] = $this->user_model->user_data();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/profile', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

View:

```
<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>'s Profile</h2>

</br>

<body>

<h4>Age: <?php echo $row['age'];?></h4>
```

The username shows up, but the age result does not. Also not showing any errors at this point, so I'm a little bit puzzled.

Comment: Why are you using `age` in where condition. Are you using `age` as unique identifier for your users.  Why dont you use `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try echo `$this->db->last_query();` in your controller after line

```
 $data['row'] = $this->user_model->user_data();
```

It will help you to get actual query executing through active record and try the same query through `phpmyadmin` you

Answer (score 0):

User `row_array` to get the row array from the database.

#### Model

```
public function user_data()
{
    $age = $this->session->userdata('age');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('age', $age);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = $query->row_array(); //<---- Change this
    return $data;
}
```

Yo Need to load the model first in the controller.

#### Controller

```
public function user()
{   
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $row = $this->user_model->user_data();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/profile', ['row' => $row]); //<--- Try this way
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

#### View

```
<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>'s Profile</h2>

</br>

<body>

<h4>Age: <?php echo $row['age'];?></h4>
```

To get your session data you need to do this:

This how you can add data in the session.
Example: while creating user login in the login process you can create the user session.

```
$setSession_data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'age'       => $age     
);

$this->session->set_userdata('your_session_name', $setSession_data);
```

And this how you can retrieve session data.

```
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('your_session_name');
print_r($session_data);
echo $session_data['username'];
echo $session_data['age'];
```

For more detail See this [Helper link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Hmm, still not showing the age. Can't figure out why. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Cuberonix Please add the error in the question. Please

Comment: I'm not getting an error, that's what's confusing. The age is just coming up blank.

Comment: Try to get session data as I show in the answer. please try and get back

Comment: If I do $session_data = $this->session->userdata('username'); it returns the username. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Alternately, if I do: $session_data = $this->session->userdata() It gives me this: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1507008901 [user_logged] => 1 [username] => testUser [loggedin] => )

Comment: what is your session name @Cuberonix ?

Comment: if you get the `username` then now what your need else ?

Comment: How do I find the session name? I need to get the age of the user to display.

Comment: When I do: echo session_name() I get: ci_session

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure session library is auto loaded.
First check what you get in session.

```
$this->session->userdata('variable name');
```

check your query what it is actually executed.

```
 $this->db->last_query();
```

Finally check out your $row variable

```
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other age values while getting your data from database? The reason age is not printed on your view might be there is no data returned from database. 
You need to - and we need - see the query executed against the database. So,

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

And where do you get the value to set session variable 'username'?